# How to optimize MAPE code in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, data-science

I need to have a MAPE function, however I was not able to find it in standard packages ... Below, my implementation of this function.

```
def mape(actual, predict): 
    tmp, n = 0.0, 0
    for i in range(0, len(actual)):
        if actual[i] <> 0:
            tmp += math.fabs(actual[i]-predict[i])/actual[i]
            n += 1
    return (tmp/n)
```

I don't like it, it's super not optimal in terms of speed. How to rewrite the code to be more Pythonic way and boost the speed?

Comment: For those that are interested, since version 0.24 `MAPE` is available in `scikit-learn` ([see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71212194/7109869)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach with [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
def mape_vectorized(a, b): 
    mask = a <> 0
    return (np.fabs(a[mask] - b[mask])/a[mask]).mean()
```

Probably a faster one with `masking` after `division` computation -

```
def mape_vectorized_v2(a, b): 
    mask = a <> 0
    return (np.fabs(a - b)/a)[mask].mean()
```

Runtime test -

```
In [217]: a = np.random.randint(-10,10,(10000))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(-10,10,(10000))
     ...: 

In [218]: %timeit mape(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop

In [219]: %timeit mape_vectorized(a,b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 273 µs per loop

In [220]: %timeit mape_vectorized_v2(a,b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 220 µs per loop
```

Comment: What is the `<>` operation?

Comment: @panc It's the same as ``!=``, it's not really Pythonic so you can forget about it

Comment: @NathanFurnal that implies it's valid python but I cannot even get it to work (just out of curiosity)

Comment: @SARose That was python 2! It's not valid in any python 3+ code

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way of doing it using `masked_Arrays` to mask division by zero is:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
masked_actual = ma.masked_array(actual, mask=actual==0)
MAPE = (np.fabs(masked_actual - predict)/masked_actual).mean()
```