# scikit-learn: How to calculate root-mean-square error (RMSE) in percentage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataset (found in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUY2ltNGVkMG05V00) of the following format.

```
 time     X   Y
0.000543  0  10
0.000575  0  10
0.041324  1  10
0.041331  2  10
0.041336  3  10
0.04134   4  10
  ...
9.987735  55 239
9.987739  56 239
9.987744  57 239
9.987749  58 239
9.987938  59 239
```

The third column (Y) in my dataset is my true value - that's what I wanted to predict (estimate). I want to do a prediction of `Y` (i.e. predict the current value of `Y` according to the previous 100 rolling values of `X`. For this, I have the following `python` script work using `random forest regression model`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

@author: deshag
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt



df = pd.read_csv('estimated_pred.csv')

for i in range(1,100):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X=pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(100)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values


y = df['Y'].values


reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
reg.fit(X,y)
modelPred = reg.predict(X)
print(modelPred)

print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPred))

meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y, modelPred)
print("MSE:", meanSquaredError)
rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
print("RMSE:", rootMeanSquaredError)
```

At the end, I measured the root-mean-square error (RMSE) and got an `RMSE` of `19.57`. From what I have read from the documentation, it says that squared errors have the same units as of the response. Is there any way to present the value of an `RMSE` in percentage? For example, to say this percent of the prediction is correct and this much wrong.

There is a `check_array` function for calculating `mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)`  in the recent version of `sklearn` but it doesn't seem to work the same way as the previous version when i try it as in the following.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import check_array

def calculate_mape(y_true, y_pred): 
y_true, y_pred = check_array(y_true, y_pred)

    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

calculate_mape(y, modelPred)
```

This is returning an error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. And this seems to be that the `check_array` function in the recent version returns only a [single value](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_array.html), unlike the previous version.

Is there any way to present the `RMSE` in percentage or calculate `MAPE` using `sklearn` for `Python`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation of `calculate_mape` is not working because you are expecting the `check_arrays` function, which was removed in `sklearn 0.16`. `check_array` is not what you want.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42251083/58866) StackOverflow answer gives a working implementation.

Comment: I made some changes, re-run and now get a value of `0.064` for MAPE but, i can't tell if this is the error or accuracy.

Comment: This is error, and it is also out of 1 in the linked implementation. If you want it out of 100 as you had before then multiply the result by 100.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, and that syntax change should be fine.