# MAPE calculation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, spyder

I want to calculate Mean Absolute percentage error (MAPE) of predicted and true values. I found a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250958/how-to-optimize-mape-code-in-python), but this gives error and shows invalid syntax in the line `mask = a <> 0`

```
    def mape_vectorized_v2(a, b): 
    mask = a <> 0
    return (np.fabs(a - b)/a)[mask].mean() 

   def mape_vectorized_v2(a, b): 
       File "<ipython-input-5-afa5c1162e83>", line 1
         def mape_vectorized_v2(a, b):
                                       ^
     SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I am using spyder3. My predicted value is a type np.array and true value is dataframe

```
type(predicted)
Out[7]: numpy.ndarray
type(y_test)
Out[8]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

How do i clear this error and proceed with MAPE Calculation ?

Edit :

```
predicted.head()
Out[22]: 
   Total_kWh
0   7.163627
1   6.584960
2   6.638057
3   7.785487
4   6.994427

y_test.head()
Out[23]: 
     Total_kWh
79         7.2
148        6.7
143        6.7
189        7.2
17         6.4

np.abs(y_test[['Total_kWh']] - predicted[['Total_kWh']]).head()
Out[24]: 
   Total_kWh
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4   0.094427
```

Comment: You need `mask = a != 0`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Python for compare by not equal need `!=`, not `<>`.

So need:

```
def mape_vectorized_v2(a, b): 
    mask = a != 0
    return (np.fabs(a - b)/a)[mask].mean()
```

Another solution from [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/294069):

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
```

Comment: This is giving me a nan. Do you know when it would yield such a value? My second array contains values that are 0, how do I modify the latter solution to include such cases?

Comment: wouldn't the first function lead to negative MAPE values for negative values in `a`? Shouldn't the calculation be `(np.fabs((a - b))/a)[mask].mean()` where the denominator is also absolute?

Answer (score 9):

The new version of scikit-learn (v0.24) has a function that will calculate MAPE.
`sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error`

All what you need is two array-like variables: `y_true` storing the actual/real values, and `y_pred` storing the predicted values.

You can refer to the official documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error).

Comment: sklearn mean_absolute_percentage_error gives wrong value, even on this doc if you see the example given, the large value of 112589990684262.48 is obtained as result.

Answer (score 8):

Both solutions are not working with zero values. This is working form me:

```
def percentage_error(actual, predicted):
    res = np.empty(actual.shape)
    for j in range(actual.shape[0]):
        if actual[j] != 0:
            res[j] = (actual[j] - predicted[j]) / actual[j]
        else:
            res[j] = predicted[j] / np.mean(actual)
    return res

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred): 
    return np.mean(np.abs(percentage_error(np.asarray(y_true), np.asarray(y_pred)))) * 100
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: np.mean(actual) could be replace for other criteria as very small float number, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual values can also be zeroes I am taking the average of the actual values in the denominator, instead of the actual values:

```py
Error = np.sum(np.abs(np.subtract(data_4['y'],data_4['pred'])))
Average = np.sum(data_4['y'])
MAPE = Error/Average
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version that is mindful of Zero:

```
    #Mean Absolute Percentage error 
def mape(y_true, y_pred,sample_weight=None,multioutput='uniform_average'):
    y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    epsilon = np.finfo(np.float64).eps
    mape = np.abs(y_pred - y_true) / np.maximum(np.abs(y_true), epsilon)
    output_errors = np.average(mape,weights=sample_weight, axis=0)
    if isinstance(multioutput, str):
        if multioutput == 'raw_values':
            return output_errors
        elif multioutput == 'uniform_average':
            # pass None as weights to np.average: uniform mean
            multioutput = None
    return np.average(output_errors, weights=multioutput)

def _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput, dtype="numeric"):
    if y_true.ndim == 1:
        y_true = y_true.reshape((-1, 1))

    if y_pred.ndim == 1:
        y_pred = y_pred.reshape((-1, 1))

    if y_true.shape[1] != y_pred.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("y_true and y_pred have different number of output "
                         "({0}!={1})".format(y_true.shape[1], y_pred.shape[1]))

    n_outputs = y_true.shape[1]
    allowed_multioutput_str = ('raw_values', 'uniform_average',
                               'variance_weighted')
    if isinstance(multioutput, str):
        if multioutput not in allowed_multioutput_str:
            raise ValueError("Allowed 'multioutput' string values are {}. "
                             "You provided multioutput={!r}".format(
                                 allowed_multioutput_str,
                                 multioutput))
    elif multioutput is not None:
        multioutput = check_array(multioutput, ensure_2d=False)
        if n_outputs == 1:
            raise ValueError("Custom weights are useful only in "
                             "multi-output cases.")
        elif n_outputs != len(multioutput):
            raise ValueError(("There must be equally many custom weights "
                              "(%d) as outputs (%d).") %
                             (len(multioutput), n_outputs))
    y_type = 'continuous' if n_outputs == 1 else 'continuous-multioutput'

    return y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to calculate MAPE which can tackle '0' denominator and it is fast.

```py
def mod_my_MAPE(y, pred):
    y = y[:][y[:]!=0]
    pred = pred[:][y[:]!=0]
    summ = np.sum(abs((y[:] - pred[:])/y[:]))
    return summ/len(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `scikit-learn` version 0.24. one is able to use [`sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html).

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/46f15a00d2324da4b9f12c9168ddda8dddb1b607/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L292) is the link for the implementation on their GitHub repo.

I just tried locally with the newest version (1.0.2).

Here is an example ([Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html))

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
>>> y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
>>> y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]
>>> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
0.5515...
```

**Note**: MAPE can be problematic, if one of the values of y_true is zero. In Scikit-learn that will result in an arbitrarily high number.

See this example ([Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html))

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
>>> y_true = [1., 0., 2.4, 7.]
>>> y_pred = [1.2, 0.1, 2.4, 8.]
>>> mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred)
112589990684262.48
```