# cannot import name 'mean_absolute_percentage_error' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, package

I receive an error message:

> cannot import name 'mean_absolute_percentage_error' from 'sklearn.metrics'

, when I run the following package:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
```

I appreciate any comments to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using? mean_absolute_percentage_error is available from version 0.24 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65216945/

Comment: That method was added in version 0.24

Comment: I checked the forum, so I need to update the version in anaconda prompt:   ```conda update conda
conda update anaconda=0.24```, is it correct? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the latest version of `scikit-learn` from forge channel:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

In order to check your installation you can use

```
conda list scikit-learn  # to see which scikit-learn version is 
installedconda list  # to see all packages installed in the active conda 
environmentpython -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"
```