# How to test a Random Forest regression model for Overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm using RandomForest for a regression model and wanted to see if my model is overfitting. Here is what I did:

I use GridSearchCV for hyperparameter tuning and then create a RandomForestRegressor with those parameters:

```
RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=b['n_estimators'], max_depth=b['max_depth'], min_samples_leaf=b['min_samples_leaf'], random_state=0)
```

Then I fit the model using the train dataset:

```
model = RF.fit(x_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

Then I predict with the test dataset:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Then I did the exact same with x_train instead of x_test:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_train)
```

Here are the results that I achieve:

```
Test Data:
MAE: 15.11
MAPE: 26.98%

Train Data:
MAE: 6.17
MAPE: 10.97%
```

As you can see there is a pretty significant difference.
Do I have a big problem with overfitting or am I doing something wrong when using x_train to predict?

Formulas for the MAE and MAPE:

**MAE:**

```
mae = sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
```

**MAPE:**

```
def percentage_error(actual, predicted):
   res = np.empty(actual.shape)
   for j in range(actual.shape[0]):
       if actual[j] != 0:
           res[j] = (actual[j] - predicted[j]) / actual[j]
       else:
           res[j] = predicted[j] / np.mean(actual)
   return res

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, y_pred): 
   return np.mean(np.abs(percentage_error(np.asarray(y_test), np.asarray(y_pred)))) * 100
```

Source for the MAPE formula:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59033147/10603410

Comment: Please show the code where you generate MAPE and MAE as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added the code to the original post!

Comment: Looks like an overfitting issue only.. I dont see any issue with the predict of X_train. Try to make the model more simpler ...

Comment: thanks for the reply! when you say make the model more simple, how exactly could I do that?

Comment: Look up how to reduce overfitting. By simpler, I mean take lesser features, regularization, dimensionality reduction using PCA, doing cross validation etc etc. As the model gets more complex with more features than necessary, it learns too much into it and doesn't generalize well on the test set.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a "If this number `x` is less than `y` then we are overfitting", it is you who need to conclude if we are overfitting.

By definition if the test  error is "much bigger than the train error", you are overfitting, but this "much bigger" is not defined - if depends on your data and what the model is used for. If your data is really "easy" (i.e easy to regress) you would expect a close train/test error. If it is really noisy you could accept a bigger difference

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply! That makes a lot of sense. For the results I posted above, the max_depth was set to 'None'. When I set max_depth to a lower value, for example max_depth = 10, the difference between the test and train results becomes much smaller, while the results for the test dataset only get slightly worse. Could this point towards what you're referring to as noisy data?

Comment: Then you are surely overfitting in the first place (deep trees overfit!). Note that just because you are not overfitting does not mean your model is "good" - it can mean it is equally bad predicting the train/test sets. An example of such is, if your model just calculates the mean of your targets. Since your train/test should come from the same distribution, the predictions of train/test set might be close to each other (no overfitting), but the errors are big (e.g if your target is a sine-curve + noise, the avg. is a really bad fit)

Comment: Okay I understand. In that case it doesn't make sense to reduce the max_depth just to reduce the overfitting problem, right? Is there anything else I can do to reduce the overfitting or is it just the nature of my data that causes this to happen?

Comment: Reducing max_depth will indeed reduce overfitting, but it will (most likely) also increase your bias (reduce your accuracy). Most of the time you would have some function to minimize/optimize e.g MAPE or AUC, and you use that metric on your validation set (test set) to find the proper hyper-parameters. You can also plot the train/validation error as a function of max-depth, where you should see the validation error fall untill a certain point where it starts raising again - that should be your sweet spot.