# MAPE calculation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, math

I need a function in javascript to calculate MAPE. (Mean absolute percentage error)
I do not want to depend on an external library and just want a vanilla javascript version of the solution.

there are quite some sample solutions in other programming language, and it would be great if someone can convert it to javascript for the use in javascript.

Formula for MAPE:

[image]

where `f_i` is the forecast value and `a_i` is the actual value.

NOTE: that i want to achieve this w/o the use of a library, since there is one library available out there, but i feel this can be achieved without the use of a library.

- https://github.com/stdlib-js/stats-incr-mape

**Some examples of MAPE in other programming languages:**

- [How to optimize MAPE code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250958/how-to-optimize-mape-code-in-python)
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-calculate-mape-in-r/

If you can write out the code in javascript, that will really help me out, since i need to use this formula.

Comment: Can you demonstrate a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself?  Can you provide input/output samples and how they are formatted?  That is, do you want the function to take a pair of arrays, or an array of pairs, or that state-based incremental one from your library link?  I can throw together something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEPbgW) but I don't know if it meets your needs because your question isn't clear enough about the requirements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: based on what you shared, that's actually what i needed. the assumption would be that both arrays would be of the same length, because i saw examples in python & R programming but dont have in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MAPE(f, a) {
 n = a.length
 if (f.length != n) throw new Error(‘f must have the same length as a!’)
 sum = 0
 for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) sum += Math.abs((a[i] - f[i])/a[i])
 return (100/n)*sum
}
```

Comment: i think it would be good if you can edit your ans so that it checks for if both array is of same length, before performing the operation. like in @ 
jcalz answer